# How do I implement a custom Brush in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, brush

Where can I find out enough info about how Brushes work to implement my own System.Windows.Media.Brush?  I can handle all of the freezable baggage, but it's not really obvious what I need to override to get it to work.

---

Yeah, so I didn't mean that I want to use a predefined brush.  I want to extend System.Windows.Media.Brush, which is an abstract class.  This is all purely for my own edification.  I'm not even sure what kind of brush I could make.  I was just trying to learn how brushes work. As in:

```
public AwesomeBrush : Brush
{

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new AwesomeBrush();
    }

    ... // concrete brush stuff

}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a little more information about what you're trying to do.  Not sure what creating a brush would take, but here's a good list of the many brushes built into wpf:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a custom WPF brush by inheriting from the `System.Windows.Media.Brush` class, because that class contains abstract members that are internal.

If you use Reflector to view the source code of `System.Windows.Media.Brush` class, you will see the following internal abstract methods:

```
internal abstract DUCE.ResourceHandle AddRefOnChannelCore(DUCE.Channel channel);
internal abstract DUCE.Channel GetChannelCore(int index);
internal abstract int GetChannelCountCore();
internal abstract DUCE.ResourceHandle GetHandleCore(DUCE.Channel channel);
internal abstract void ReleaseOnChannelCore(DUCE.Channel channel);
```

These must be overridden but cannot be because they are internal.

**Note:** Edited my answer because previous answer was about `System.Drawing.Brush` and irrelevant to this question. Special thanks to Mikko Rantanen for his comment.

Comment: You can inherit from Brush class - as you said, it's abstract and abstract classes MUST be inherited.

Comment: What is it about Brush that makes it unable to be inherited?  I know all of the implementations are sealed, but we should be able to derive from Brush, right?

Comment: Damn you internal constructors!  I've been foiled by you before!

Comment: @M. Jahedbozorgan: What you state here is correct of the System.Drawing.Brush class... The WPF version CAN be derived from. See System.Windows.Media.Brush.

Comment: The constructor is not internal. protected Brush(); / Declaring Type: System.Windows.Media.Brush / Assembly: PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0 - however you are close to the problem. The brush does have internal abstract methods, just not the constructor. One of the worst is `internal abstract DUCE.ResourceHandle AddRefOnChannelCore(DUCE.Channel channel);` in which the parameters are of internal type as well. These must be overridden but cannot be as they are internal.

Comment: @Josh. That is quite wrong. There is nothing stopping you deriving from the System.Drawing.Brush class. Deriving from the WPF Brush is impossible though. Not because of the constructor but because of the other abstract internal methods.

Comment: @Mikko Rantanen: Maybe so, but the point is that System.Drawing.Brush is different than System.Windows.Media.Brush and is irrelevant to this discussion. As you said in your answer, it appears that only Microsoft can implement child classes for Brush even though the documentation refers to inheritors.

Comment: How can I force the compiler to let me inherit from it anyway? I know it's not something I should do in production code; I simply want to experiment with it. I know it's possible to override member access using reflection; is there something similar I can do here?

Answer (score 10):

I had a quick look at the existing brushes using the [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). It seems like their implementation is pretty closed up and depends on lots of `internal` plumbing. While it might be possible to implement your own brush it seems like it is not a supported option. It could even be that the WPF controls are tied tightly to the existing brushes and will not work with a custom one.

Most likely the best way to achieve something resembling custom brushes is to use the [DrawingBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) with some complex drawing logic. You can compose drawing brush from complex shapes using other brushes so this should let you achieve the required goal.

**Update after edit**

As this is for education, you might be best off downloading the Reflector and using that to see how the brushes work. They are not meant to be self-implemented and since they rely on some `internal` classes to which programmers do not have access normally it will be quite hard to do so.

Though what makes it interesting is that the [Brush documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx) does have a remark for inheritors to guide in the correct way to inherit from the Brush.

**More updates**

When poking around I found a quite neat way to achieve something similar on a [chinese blog](http://translate.google.com/translate?prev=hp&hl=fi&js=n&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.csdn.net%2Fxeonol%2Farchive%2F2007%2F12%2F17%2F1943067.aspx&sl=zh-CN&tl=en). The trick there is to use a markup extension so it just looks like a brush. In reality it creates a new image brush based on its attributes. Seems he came to the same conclusion that there are some internal classes which prevent the easy implementation.

Comment: I suspect that's the case, as well.  I can't imagine anything that couldn't be done with the brush implementations provided in the framework, I was just wondering if there might be fun ways to componentize such things to make it really slick for reuse.

Comment: Added an update which achieves something similar without extending Brush.

Comment: I wonder if the note in the brush documentation to inheritors was for Microsoft personal and was not supposed to make it into the final doc. As I look at Reflector, it looks like a lot of the essential fields in Brush and also GradientBrush are marked internal. So we can't get at them.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer; pity this is not the accepted one. I do wish there were a more flexible way to implement a custom `Brush`-derived class. The idea to use `DrawingBrush` is fine for some scenarios, but I don't see how one would use it for others. For example, what if I want to implement a variant of `LinearGradientBrush` that includes some kind of gamma control (i.e. so the interpolation between stops isn't strictly linear)?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question of why you might want to have a custom brush, consider a complex geometry and you want to fill it with a gradient that matches the shape while changing colours radially from the center of the shape (or any arbitrary starting point).

There is no way to do this with a static fill (which eliminates pretty much all the existing brushes). Short of replicating the object over and over and nesting them (and working out the hulling to make it all look right), filling each one with a different colour, the only practical way is to have a brush that can look at the object being filled.

This is actually doable in Forms.

But it doesn't look like there's any way to do it in WPF, which is unfortunate.

In fact, WPF's brushes are at the same time surprisingly powerful AND surprisingly limited. They're clearly designed to some concept model, but I'm not at all sure it's one that's useful beyond some pretty trivial visual effects, and as usual, it's been made more complex with strange (poorly documented) parameters that makes doing the very simple, somewhat  complicated.

Answer (score 4):

I tried every possible angle for a solution to making a custom brush, from using MarkupExtensions to messing around with TypeConverter attributes, then it dawwned on me: you simply create a wrapper class based on DependencyObject, create a DependencyProperty  of type Brush, implement your customization then Bind to the Brush DependencyProperty.

Afterwards, put the custom brush in Resources

```
  <l:CustomBrush x:Key="CustomBrush" Brush="Magenta" />
```

Then Bind to it:

```
  <Line X1="0" Y1="-5" X2="200" Y2="-5" 
        Stroke="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomBrush}, Path=Brush}" 
        StrokeThickness="12"/>
```

I think this is better than the MarkupExtension solution because you can't put one in Resources and therefore you have to redefine the custom settings every time you use it.

In any case, this would seem to be a simple solution to inheriting from any Wpf object, and with the flexibility of Bindings you can also bind to members of the wrapped Wpf object itself.

Here's the simple class:

```
public class CustomBrush : DependencyObject
{
   public CustomBrush()
   {
      this.Brush = Brushes.Azure;      
   }

   #region Brush DependencyProperty

   [BindableAttribute(true)]
   public Brush Brush
   {
     get { return (Brush)GetValue(BrushProperty); }
     set { SetValue(BrushProperty, value); }
   }
   public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(
         "Brush",
         typeof(Brush),
         typeof(CustomBrush),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

   #endregion         
}
```