# WPF extra gradient brushes

Tags: .net, wpf, sdk, gradient

Does anyone know if there are any extra gradient brushes available for WPF, such as a contour fill? Or even whether it is possible to make one? [Linear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush.aspx) and [Radial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush.aspx) do not always fill shapes in the desired way. I note that both derive from [System.Windows.Media.GradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientbrush.aspx) which suggests that it might be possible to make more. I am aware of extra [effects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.effect.aspx) in the Expression SDK but not any extra types of brush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794512/how-do-i-implement-a-custom-brush-in-wpf) deals with a similar matter. Basically, you can't inherit from Brush.