# How do I inherit from Brush, so I can add a Name property?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example:

```
public class DesignerPatternBrush : Brush
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to define my own `Brush` class by adding a new property called `Name`, but there is a compiler error:

> error CS0534: 'Brushes.DesignerPatternBrush' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.Freezable.CreateInstanceCore()'

How can I add a `Name` property to a `Brush` type?

Note this related question: [How do I implement a custom Brush in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/794512/) It answers the question of why it is not possible to literally inherit `Brush`. But is there some other way (e.g. using an attached property) to achieve the same effect I want?

Comment: How do you intend to use it?  Sounds like encapsulation may be easier that inheritance in this case.

Comment: @DStanley I just wanna store more information like a name for a brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compile error message says is Brush an abstract class --> you have to implement its abstract members

to let Visual Studio do all the work for you there exist a shortcut.

Select the Brush class and press Alt + Shift + F10 --> Enter
the abstract class gets automatically implemented:

```
public class T : Brush
{

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

but this will not work with the Brush class. Visual Studio auto-implements all methods which are visible, but the Brush class defines some methods as internal abstract

i.e:

```
internal abstract int GetChannelCountCore();
```

As the Brush is defined in PresentationCore we will never be able to override the abstract method outside the assembly... --> impossible to inherit from the class

Comment: Just doing this won't work, there are a bunch of missing abstract methods in brush that I don't seem to see in the brush declaration.
GetChannelCountCore(), GetChannelCore(int), AddrefOnChannelCore... at least didn't work for me anyway

Comment: Didn't know you could do `Alt` + `Shift` + `F10` as well as `Ctrl` + `.` - not sure if you did either :P

Comment: no i didnt know. sounds strange but i find alt + shift + f10 quite intuitive ;)

Comment: @Andy This works for me, by implementing it it only includes one member and then it allows me to build.

Comment: @fix_likes_coding How?! It's such a ball ache extending your fingers across the keyboard for three keys :P

Comment: Ok, I must have something else going on then.

Comment: Looks like inherit from Brush is too difficult. @Andy

Comment: @Andy wait a sec, im just testing something. i think its linked to the different assemblys in the System.Windows Namespace

Comment: seems it's not just the brush that does this Transform and Geometry are the same.

Answer (score 3):

It means you need to implement all abstract methods that were inherited from Brush and its ancestors. In this case it's `CreateInstanceCore()` method of the `Freezable` class.

Why do you need a named brush? You can create a brush and store it into a ResourceDictionary (under a given key, which is basically a name) for your view/window/application - maybe you are looking for this solution.

More on that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx

Comment: I tried, but how to retrieve the Name or Key after creating a brush object. Can I do something like the following? Create a brush object: brush = userControl.FindResource("MyBrush1"). To retrieve the name of the brush: brush.Name

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit an abstract class you have some members that you need to `Override`. You will notice a little dropdown under `Brush`. If you press `CTRL` + `.` whilst your cursor is on `Brush` it will ask you to implement it, I press `Enter` after`CTRL` + `Space`. When you implement it you will see this:

```
  protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
```

Comment: Thank u. That short cut is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution: Instead of inheritance, you can create a class that alters a Brush properties throw attached properties. For example:
I created a class named "HatchBrushes" that can create 55 DrawingBrushes with deferent hatch styles (similar to WinForms HatchBrush.. In fact this part of code belongs to another programer)
The HatchBrushes class defines 4 attached properties that controls the hatch brush appearance: HatchStyle, Background, Foreground, and PenThickness. All these properties register a PropertyChangedCallBck sub named "OnHatchChanged", where I can change the properties of the DrawingBrush:

```
Shared Sub OnHatchChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim DBrush = TryCast(d, DrawingBrush)
        If DBrush Is Nothing Then Return
        Dim B = GetHatchBrush(GetHatchStyle(DBrush), GetBackground(DBrush), GetForeground(DBrush), GetPenThickness(DBrush))
        DBrush.Drawing = B.Drawing.CloneCurrentValue
        DBrush.Stretch = B.Stretch
        DBrush.ViewportUnits = B.ViewportUnits
        DBrush.Viewport = B.Viewport
        DBrush.TileMode = B.TileMode
    End Sub
```

Note that "GetHatchBrush" is a function that creates a DrawingBrush with the desired HatchStyle. I wont write it here because it is too long.

Now, I can color the background of the window with a Horizontal-lines Hatch with simole xaml code like this:

```
<DrawingBrush c:HatchBrushes.HatchStyle="Horizontal"
   c:HatchBrushes.Background="Red" 
   c:HatchBrushes.Foreground="Yellow" 
   c:HatchBrushes.PenThickness="2"/>
```

Comment: _"I wont write it here because it is too long"_ -- that's unfortunate, because that would make the difference between a useful answer and a non-useful one. Note that the OP is actually asking just to add a `Name` property, so you _could_ have demonstrated _that_ instead of introducing the more-complex "hatched brush" scenario. Please consider improving your answer, as frankly it's the only one that's even come close to actually _helping_ the OP accomplish their goal.